# How does Lazy Evaluation and Eager Evaluation work in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, lazy-evaluation

I understand Streams are lazy until terminal method is called on the stream.
What I know is that after terminal method is called all the intermediate methods are executed in order of their calling.

But with the following program I can't get my head around how stream is working. Here is the code, I have tried.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

class TestEagerLazy
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>();

        a.add(4);a.add(5);a.add(8);
        a.add(7);a.add(3);a.add(65);
        a.add(87);a.add(2);a.add(12);
        a.add(58);a.add(42);

        Stream<Integer> st = a.stream().filter(b->{System.out.println("Tested: " + b);return (b%2)==0;});

        Spliterator<Integer> it = st.spliterator();

        System.out.println("\n\nIterator Results:");
        while(it.tryAdvance((j)->System.out.println("iter: "+j)));


        System.out.println("Last Statement");


    }
}
```

The output I expected assuming tryAdvance on the stream's spliterator is as follows:

```
Iterator Results:
Tested: 4
Tested: 5
Tested: 8
Tested: 7
Tested: 3
Tested: 65
Tested: 87
Tested: 2
Tested: 12
Tested: 58
Tested: 42
iter: 4
iter: 8
iter: 2
iter: 12
iter: 58
iter: 42
Last Statement
```

But the output I got was as follows:

```
Iterator Results:
Tested: 4
iter: 4
Tested: 5
Tested: 8
iter: 8
Tested: 7
Tested: 3
Tested: 65
Tested: 87
Tested: 2
iter: 2
Tested: 12
iter: 12
Tested: 58
iter: 58
Tested: 42
iter: 42
Last Statement
```

What is the exact program flow? How does program flow from tryAdvance to filter on the stream and back.

Comment: What do you think [`tryAdvance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#tryAdvance-java.util.function.Consumer-) does, and why do you think so? --- The entire point is that it "tries to advance the stream by one element" and performs the given action on it. *One element at a time!*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Stateless streams are designed to handle a possibly infinite amount of elements. For this to be possible, the stream cannot attempt to evaluate each operation on all of the elements at once.

Sequential streams always execute the pipeline one element at a time. Each element goes through the entire pipeline before the next element starts. This is what allows lazy evaluation to be effective. It allows the stream to short-circuit, such as with [`findFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--) or [`allMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-). If all of the elements were processed at once at each stage, streams would not be able to handle infinite data sources, such as from [`Stream.iterate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#iterate-T-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-).

The output of your code demonstrates that the elements go through the pipeline one at a time:

```
Iterator Results:
Tested: 4   // starting 1st element
iter: 4     // ending 1st element
Tested: 5   // starting 2nd element (fails the filter)
Tested: 8   // starting 3rd element
iter: 8     // ending 3rd element
Tested: 7   // starting 4th element (fails the filter)
...
Last Statement
```

These behaviors are explained more generally in the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps).

Comment: As the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#package.description) says: *Laziness-seeking. Many stream operations, such as filtering, mapping, or duplicate removal, can be implemented lazily, exposing opportunities for optimization. For example, "find the first `String` with three consecutive vowels" need not examine all the input strings.* Said another way, the `filter()` method is not called until needed, aka lazily. It's really the definition of "lazy". *(But maybe they should have called it "procrastinating"?)*

Comment: @Andreas: I don’t think that “procrastinating” is appropriate as that would imply that the Stream implementation does other things (writing Stackoverflow contributions?) instead of even starting to work…